# Testing Optimistic Locking in Java EE environment

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, optimistic-locking

As I understand if a row in a database table is updated simultaneously by multiple threads the database would flag an error.

In our production environment we have 2 Tomcat servers in a cluster. It might happen that the two users are directed to each one of the Tomcat servers at the same time and they update the same record in the database table. As a result, an exception would be thrown.

How do I simulate this situation on my local machine? Or how would I do it some environment which is same as production?

Technology that I am working on: Java 6, Spring 3, Hibernate, MS SQL Server 2008 and Tomcat 7.

Comment: I recommend using a ACID compliant Database, you wouldn't need to worry abt them much

Comment: You think MS SQL Server is not ACID compliant? My original question is how do we unit test such scenario even if the database handles it.

Comment: Sorry, though, you were on MySQL (not using INNODB), for unit testing, you can try firing the same update query using threads multiple times

Comment: @Akash MS SQL is not MySql

Comment: @Adi, I know, I just mis-read it in the first place

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand if a row in a database table is updated simultaneously
>   by multiple threads the database would flag an error.

Not necessarily. If you run two statements like these below,

```
UPDATE foo SET bar=baz WHERE bah=doh;
```

database could simply schedule to run these queries one after another. But there are [plenty of possibilities](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/309/code-to-simulate-deadlock) [for a deadlock](http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/databases/mssql/f676.shtml) and, generally speaking, result depends on your queries and their timing, data set, etc.

Comment: Ok, but how do we reliably unit test such situation? And I am talking about the race condition and not deadlock.

Comment: Do you really think you can uncover a bug in MS SQL because of simulating some race condition? I would suggest you to take a **real life scenario** first and take it from there. For me, you are solving a non-existing problem. Anyway, if you want to build a unit test for it, you can try [JDBC interceptor](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/04/19/building-extensions-jdbc-pool). The latter can be programmed to mimic DB responses in any way you like.

Comment: I am not trying to uncover anything. Also what I am talking about is real life scenario. A simultaneous multiple updates on the same row in a database table can happen in any clustered environment. And it would be beneficial if we can simulate it which I am sure you won't disagree.

Comment: You need to simulate this on a test server first and be 100% sure on what kind of exceptions you get.

Answer (score 0):

You wan't to simulate the scenario. I read it as you want to test the code which handles optimistic lock exception. I would simply simulate the class which throws exception and explicitly throw OptimisticLockException. Use the simulated class inside exception handler in test environment and write a test fr exception handler.

I believe you are not worried about testing whether optimistic lock is working or not. As it is the job of Hibernate developers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate it by using two transactions.
Start the first tx.
Start the second tx.
Make some changes in the first TX and commit it.
Make some changes in the second TX and commit it.
Hibernate should give you the OptimisticLockException.